# jquery, images type

Tags: jquery, image

I'd  like to change image type with jquery, for example:

```
<img width="250" height="61" alt="Stack Overflow" src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png"/>
```

to

```
<a href="/"><img width="250" height="61" alt="Stack Overflow" src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.gif"/></a>
```

To change ".png: in ".gif" (in this case)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:  (Assuming that all `.png` images have equivalent `.gif` images on the server)

```
$('img[src$=".png"]').each(function(img) { 
    img.attr('src', img.attr('src').replace(/\.png$/, '.gif'));
});
```

Comment: I think he is trying to change images wrapped in links. the initial selector should be something like $('a img[src$=".png"]')

Comment: I think he just made a mistake when copying the source.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$('img').each(function()
{
    this.src = this.src.replace(/png$/, '.gif');
});
```